# This is a question in number theory. It seemed I can't start the proof.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, modular-arithmetic, primitive-roots

How can this be solved?

I knew that the concept of an order of an integer is needed, but rather than that I think I'm really lost with the proofs.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please type your questions instead of posting images.  Images can't be browsed and are not accessible to those using screen readers.  If you need help formatting math on this site, here's a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Have you tried, say, evaluating $c^2$ as a function of $a$?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the community. Have you tried just expanding out $c^2 = (a-a^3)^2$ and $d^2$ and using the fact that $a^8\equiv 1\mod p$

Comment: I have not tried it yet. I think I'm being confused with the given p ≡ 1 (mod 8). Where does it actually be applied?

Comment: $p\equiv1\pmod{8}$ is to guarantee existence of an element of order $8$.

Answer (score 3):

$$a^8-1\equiv 0 \implies (a^4+1)(a^4-1)\equiv 0 \implies a^4 \equiv -1 \pmod p$$

$$c^2=(a-a^3)^2=a^2-2a^4+a^6=a^2(1+a^4)-2a^4\equiv 2 \pmod p$$

$$d^2=(a+a^3)^2=a^2+2a^4+a^6=a^2(1+a^4)+2a^4\equiv -2 \pmod p$$

Comment: Nice ($+1$); technically, I think you mean $a^8-1\equiv0\land a^4-1\not\equiv0\implies (a^4+1)(a^4-1)\equiv0\land a^4-1\not\equiv 0\implies a^4\equiv-1\pmod p$

Comment: Yes. Thank you!

Comment: i.e. $\,a^4\equiv -1,\ b=\pm a^3\Rightarrow\, a^2+b^2\equiv 0\Rightarrow (a+b)^2\equiv 2ab\equiv \pm2\ \ $

Comment: @J.W.T and the algebraic essence is clearer if we exploit symmetry, as I highlight in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: exploit innate symmetry: $\ \ \underbrace{\overbrace{-a^4 = 1^{\phantom{|}}_{\phantom{.}}\!\!}^{\!\!\!\!\textstyle \color{#0a0}{(-a^3)}a\!=\! 1}}_{\!\!\!\!\!\!\textstyle(\color{#c00}{-a^2})a^2\! =\! 1}\Rightarrow\ (a+\overbrace{a^{-1}}^{\!\!\textstyle \color{#0a0}{-a^3}})^2 = a^2+\underbrace{a^{-2}}_{\!\textstyle \color{#c00}{-a^2}}+ 2\, =\, 2$

Comment: $(b)$ is the same, replacing the sum by the difference $\,(a-a^{-1})^2\ \ $